# How to reuse mongoose connection created in app module inside an npm module

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have an npm package which performs some query on mongoose models. The app module also creates a mongoose connection. The npm package is added as a dependency in the app module. How can the npm package reuse the connection created in the app module?

Comment: Please share your code so we can understand the question better.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to not include any credential, including the connection to your database, in a library. If you want to reuse the credential across your different apps, it is better to write a connect function in your library with the credentials as parameter. Then create a central .env file for storing the secretive data and get the data from the file. Or if you would like to store it elsewhere, you can consider AWS Env or Vault.